# Finitely many repeated replacements

Tags: replacement

I'm looking for good practices to replace a given function recursively n times by itself with its arguments. The following example (for n=2) hopefully makes it clear:

```
f[a_] := d[a + b] - d[a - b]
g[a_] := f[a + b] - f[a - b]
h[a_] := g[a + b] - g[a - b]
h[a]
(*-d[a - 3 b] + 3 d[a - b] - 3 d[a + b] + d[a + 3 b]*)
```

I came up with

```
repl[func_] := func /. (d[x_] -> d[x + b] - d[x - b])
Nest[repl, d[a], 3]
```

which works ok (and doesn't look like total nonsense to me). But now I got curious, do you know of any immediate improvements or better methods to do this?

Comment: Looks fine to me, if you don't want to define `repl` then `ReplaceAll[d[x_] -> d[x + b] - d[x - b]]` could be used as the first argument to `Nest` (or an anonymous function could also be used).

Comment: @C.E. How would you define an anonymous function for this task. Unfortunately I can't make it work…

Comment: Use `# /. d[x_] -> d[x + b] - d[x - b] &` as the first argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated) with the option `MaxIterations->3`:

```
res = ReplaceRepeated[d[a], d[x_]->d[x+b]-d[x-b], MaxIterations->3]
```

> ReplaceRepeated::rrlim: Exiting after d[a] scanned 3 times.
>
> -d[a - 3 b] + d[a - b] - d[a + b] - 2 (-d[a - b] + d[a + b]) + d[a + 3 b]

This agrees with your answer after expanding:

```
h[a] == Expand[res]
```

> True

The syntax coloring is odd, though, might be a buglet.

Answer (score 4):

Asking for a "better" method you should probably give some metric what is meant by "better. Is it efficiency? Is it easiness of generalization? Anyhow, if you would stick to built-in function in hope that they are more efficient one of the options could be:

```
n = 3;
DifferenceDelta[d[a - n b], {a, n, 2 b}]
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Yes, `DifferenceDelta[]` is the right solution for that specific example, but I believe the OP only used it as a toy example, and wanted more general guidelines.